# React date picker with Material-UI

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm using Date picker from Material UI. The code responsible for it looks like:

```
import { DatePicker } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

          <Field
            name="birthDate"
            component={DatePicker}
            placeholder="Birth Date"
            container="inline"
            format={ null }
          />
```

It's a lil' bit changed, by erikras for redux form, but works quite similar like normal material ui date picker.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

### My goal is

I'm sending it's value as API request, but **unfortunately** API accepts the Date only in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. And MaterialUI date picker gives

**`2017-05-04T22:00:00.000Z`** format. How can I change it into just `2017-05-04`?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The date is given as a Date object. Manipulate it just like any other date, for example using moment.js

Comment: @IngoBürk I've fixed it already. Thanks :)

Comment: I personally prefer the moment js package for this. Super simple and you can convert it to any format you want.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tried the library itself in depth however if it return that date in that format you could just take what you need from that if it is a string you could use the substring() method and giving it the desired part start and end. lets Say

```
result = 2017-05-04T22:00:00.000Z;
var stringNeeded = result.substring(0,10)
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but I think that this solution isn't that well, seems kinda hard coded. I think that this substring or even slice methods can give some unexpected results sometimes.

Comment: The other option is to used a date library optimize to handle those events normally I would handle my dates with momentjs I totally recommend you using it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of substring, I my opinion, better to use moment lib http://momentjs.com/
which allows to format date time values to any format you can imagine
**moment(result).format('YYYY-MM-DD')**